# Разделяемая память в задаче производителя и потребителя

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток, мне попался на глаза код который реализует данную задачу, но я никак не могу понять как он выполняется и почему.
В особенности каким образом вызываются и выполняются producer() и consumer().
Как вижу, сама память выделяется используя функции System V, когда семафоры используются POSIX. Вот собственно и main() :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 10

int L = 0;

struct sharedmem
{
    sem_t mutex;          
    sem_t buffer_full;    
    sem_t buffer_empty;   
    FIFO buff; // тут наша очередь, куда наш производитель кладёт буквы
//для очереди реализованны банальные функции типо
// Pop(FIFO & val) - достать элемент из очереди val
// Push(FIFO & val, char c) - положить элемент в очередь val
};

struct sharedmem *shared;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int semid;
    semid = semget(1024, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0600);

    int shmid;
    shmid = shmget(1024, sizeof(shared), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    shared = (struct sharedmem*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    shared->count = 0;
    sem_init(&shared->mutex, 1, 1);
    sem_init(&shared->buffer_full, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&shared->buffer_empty, 1, N);

    pid_t children[2];

    children[0] = fork();
    if(children[0] == 0) consumer();

    children[1] = fork();
    if(children[1] == 0) producer();

    waitpid(children[0], NULL, 0);
    waitpid(children[1], NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Это функция производителя

```
void producer()
{
    char let;

    while(1)
    {
        let = random_letter();
        sem_wait(&shared->buffer_empty);
        sem_wait(&shared->mutex);

        Push(&shared->buff, let);  

        sem_post(&shared->mutex);
        sem_post(&shared->buffer_full);

        printf("Producer added: %s\n", &let);
        Sleep();// засыпает на рандомное время
    }
}
```

Это потребителя

```
void consumer()
{
    char let;

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&shared->buffer_full);
        sem_wait(&shared->mutex);

        let = Pop(&shared->buff);

        sem_post(&shared->mutex);
        sem_post(&shared->buffer_empty);

        printf("Consumer read and deleted: %s\n", &let);
        Sleep();// засыпает на рандомное время
    }
}
```

приблизительный результат программы :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем вопрос ? программа работает корректно !

Comment: Я не понимаю как вызываются функции производителя и потребителя

Comment: Функция fork создаёт паралельный поток (thread, в win вместо fork часто используется CreateThread, 0- означает что вы находитесь в другом потоке), у вас их создаётся два.  Один вызывает только producer, а другой только consumer. У тех кто пишет под линукс есть сленг "форкаться")) создавать поток функцией fork.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а откуда `fork()` знает, что создать для текущего треда?

Comment: Смотрите, поток делится на два. Один даёт не ноль, другой даёт ноль.  Если даёт ноль - вы заходите в процедуру с глухим циклом. Форк всегда создаёт ещё один thread, на входе один thread, на выходе два. Один с нулём, другой без. Часто даже делают `if (fork()) { /*первый поток*/  } else  { /*второй поток*/}`

Comment: @nick_n_a, такая просьба, я пишу другой проект, который сдавать через час, он не работает, не могли бы прикинуть из-за чего, вот ссылка на http://pastebin.com/sFwpwmXA, всё описание внутри!

Comment: Я думаю что к-во sem_wait и sem_post должно быть *одинаковое* как минимум (как у вас в примере). Выровняйте их к-во для начала. А в задании оно у вас разное. Задачка сложная, что ещё не так навскидку не скажу. Нарисуйте на бумажке как ветвится программа и правильно расставьте блокировки.

Comment: @nick_n_a, но вот та часть, которая находится в main(), правильно ли она реализована?